# Grant read permissions on RecycleBin for gMSA

Tags: active-directory, recycle-bin

I need to grant read permissions on RecycleBin for an gMSA account. So I have tried:

```
dsacls "CN=Deleted Objects,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com" /g DOMAIN\gMSA_account$:LCRP
```

It gives me error: *Insufficient access rights to perform the operation.*
CMD started on domain controller as administrator.
User is a member of Domain & Enterprise Administrators.

Any suggestions how to do it?

Thanks,
Adam.